# Ionic infinite scroll doesn't work on all android devices

Tags: javascript, cordova, ionic-framework, hybrid-mobile-app

I'm currently developing an ionic app and successfully implemented an infinite scroll feature. It works fine on desktop browsers and newer android devices, however, i'm having problems with phones that run android version 4.1 or less.

**The problem:**

I open the page, it loads and displays the first 20 items just fine, i scroll to the bottom, the next 20 items load, but it doesn't let me scroll any further to see the next 20 items.

Here is a GIF showing how it looks on my desktop (the way it's supposed to work). **[desktop gif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l9HMr.gif)**

Here is another GIF showing how it looks on my xperia phone (note how it doesn't let me scroll further on newly loaded items). **[xperia gif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dHmAu.gif)**

However, when i refresh the page, or turn the phone into landscape mode after the next 20 items loaded, the scrolling works just fine so it seems like the phone doesn't know that the screen height changed when the new items loaded so i thought i could get it fixed by simply adding  `$ionicScrollDelegate.resize();`  to tell the view to recalculate the size of its container, but that doesn't seem to fix it either.

**Here is my JavaScript code:**

```
.controller('TestCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {
   $scope.items = [];
   $scope.page = 1;
   $scope.totalPages = 1;


   $scope.loadMore = function() {
     if ($scope.page <= $scope.totalPages) {
       $http.get('http://localhost/test/recent/' + $scope.page).success(function(items) {
         var i = items.data.length;
         $scope.totalPages = items.pages;
         $scope.items = $scope.items.concat(items.data);

         $scope.$broadcast('scroll.infiniteScrollComplete');

         $scope.page = $scope.page + 1;
         if ($scope.page == $scope.totalPages + 1) {
           $scope.noMoreItemsAvailable = true;
         }
       });
     }
   }
 }])
```

**HTML:**

```
<ion-view view-title="Hello Stackoverflow">
  <ion-content>

    <a class="item" ng-repeat="item in items">
        {{item.title}}
        <span class="item-note">
            {{ item.timestamp | myDate }}
        </span>
    </a>

    <ion-infinite-scroll ng-if="!noMoreItemsAvailable" on-infinite="loadMore()" distance="10%"></ion-infinite-scroll>
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

I've been stuck with this problem for2 days, googled for hours and tried many different things, but i couldn't find anything that fixed it.

Comment: I've reported the issue here: https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/issues/9443

Answer (score 1):

Use `collection-repeat` instead of `ng-repeat`. It doesn't seem like Ionic with `ng-repeat` refreshes the view.

Comment: thankx it work for me.. but can you tell me what should i use if i dont have any repeater, but have only form that covering vertical space and need scrolling

Answer (score 1):

I have found a workaround... Change from this

```
<ion-content>
```

to

```
<ion-content overflow-scroll='false'>
```

to disable native scrolling in this particular view.

Comment: I had an issue where the on-infinite function was not called on device, just in desktop browser. I also had an ion-refresher in the same view. I applied your fix and now it works, thank you!