# ng-repeat + ion-infinite-scroll doesn't work on real android

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, cross-platform

i've been working with ionic cross platform apps at 2 weeks, so, i'm very noob about it.

Right now, i'm found a issue with ng-repeat [exactly like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36000494/ionic-infinite-scroll-doesnt-work-on-all-android-devices).
And yes, the collection-repeat can fix the problem, but create another.
on my case, each item have different size, and the collection-repeat can't calculate it dynamically.
this is my list repeat:

```
     <ion-list>
        <ion-item class="list card" ng-repeat="feed in feeds" type="item-text-wrap" href="#/tab/feed/{{feed.id_geral}}">
            <div class="item item-avatar">
                <img width="50" src="http://192.168.1.14/vogo/files/perfil/p/{{feed.img_perfil}}">
                <h2>{{feed.nome_perfil }}</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="item item-body">
                <img ng-show="feed.img_link.length > 3"
                     class="full-image" src="{{feed.img_link}}">
                <img ng-show="feed.video.length > 3"
                     class="full-image" src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/{{feed.video}}/sddefault.jpg" />
                <p>{{feed.post}}</p>
                <p>
                    <a href="#" class="subdued">1 Like</a>
                    <a href="#" class="subdued">5 Comments</a>
                </p>
            </div>
            <div class="item tabs tabs-secondary tabs-icon-left">
                <a class="tab-item" href="#">
                    <i class="icon ion-thumbsup"></i> Like
                </a>
                <a class="tab-item" href="#">
                    <i class="icon ion-chatbox"></i> Comment
                </a>
                <a class="tab-item" href="#">
                    <i class="icon ion-share"></i> Share
                </a>
            </div>
        </ion-item>
    </ion-list>
```

I've been trying to workaround by this way

```
<div id="dummyRender"  class="list card">
        <div class="item item-avatar">
            <img width="50" src="http://192.168.1.14/vogo/files/perfil/p/{{feed.img_perfil}}">
            <h2>{{dummy.nome_perfil }}</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="item item-body">
            <img ng-show="dummy.img_link.length > 3"
                 class="full-image" src="{{dummy.img_link}}">
            <img ng-show="dummy.video.length > 3"
                 class="full-image" src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/{{feed.video}}/sddefault.jpg" />
            <p>{{dummy.post}}</p>
            <p>
                <a href="#" class="subdued">1 Like</a>
                <a href="#" class="subdued">5 Comments</a>
            </p>
        </div>
        <div class="item tabs tabs-secondary tabs-icon-left">
            <a class="tab-item" href="#">
                <i class="icon ion-thumbsup"></i> Like
            </a>
            <a class="tab-item" href="#">
                <i class="icon ion-chatbox"></i> Comment
            </a>
            <a class="tab-item" href="#">
                <i class="icon ion-share"></i> Share
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
```

and created on controller a function to handle the height

```
var dummy = document.getElementById("dummyRender");

$scope.renderHeight = function (feedIten) {
    $scope.dummy = feedIten;
    return dummy.clientHeight;
};
```

called on

```
<ion-item class="list card" collection-repeat="feed in feeds" type="item-text-wrap" href="#/tab/feed/{{feed.id_geral}}"  item-height="renderHeight(feed)">
```

but it just work with texts.

someone can help-me workaround this using ng-repeat or collection-repeat or something else?

Thx, sorry my english skills!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot work this is my sad answer

This has no solution, it is an android 4.4< [issue](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/issues/1322) and can't be fixed yet, so you cant use ng-repeat with ion-infinite-scroll if you want to accept androids 4.4 and lowers.

And you can just work with repeat list that have the same size, it's not possible to work with dynamic sizes yet.